# Navigate with keyboard in lightbox / recognize 'onkeypress' as 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onkeypress

I try to navigate with keyboard arrows Left/Right through my lightbox, but my script doesn't work.
It will be great if the script recognizes 'onkeypress' as 'onclick', because I have to use 'onclick' for Google Analytics Stats.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Script :

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
var keymap = {};


keymap[ 37 ] = ".prev";

keymap[ 39 ] = ".next";

$( document ).on( "keyup", function(event) {
    var href,
        selector = keymap[ event.which ];
    if ( selector ) {
        href = $( selector ).attr( "href" );
        if ( href ) {
            window.location = href;
          }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<li>
  <a href="#example-01" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + '#example-01']);"><img src="images/thumbs/example-01.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="lb-overlay" id="example-01">
        <img src="images/full/example-01.jpg" />
                <div>
                    <a href="#example-00" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + '#example-00']);" class="prev">PREV</a>
                    <a href="#example-02" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + '#example-02']);" class="next">NEXT</a>
                </div>
     </div>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for my problem :

```
var current = 0;
    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37:
                $('.lb-prev')[--current].click();
                break;

            case 39:
                $('.lb-next')[++current].click();
                break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say try:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            $('.prev')[0].click();
            break;

        case 39:
            $('.next')[0].click();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nothing seems to work good. I edit the script in my question. Now I can navigate with keyboard arrows, but there's another problem. When I press right arrow (next), the current image changes to the second of my lightbox, and when I press left arrow (prev), the current image changes to the last of my lightbox. It does this for each current image..

Comment: Maybe you should target specific next/prev button, i don't really understand what you are talking about. I was just trying to fix your previous posted code, now with the new one, this answer doesn't make much sense, i'm afraid. Now if you want more specific/relevant help, you should replicate your issue online, e.g, on jsFiddle

Comment: Ahah, don't be afraid, I think I will find the solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code wasn't complete but helps me a lot, you will find a new edit of your code in my answer of my own question :)